# CSS functions, youtube and borders in : Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

i've been doing HTML, CSS and Javascript for two years now and there's always the same problem occured. I make my site, I try it out on Mozilla Firefox and it works all fine just as I expected. Then when I open it in Internet Explorer: the divs don't have there border, the frame's border is'nt transparent, the CSS functions like 
`#divID:hover {background-color: black;}` 
doesn't work anymore and the Youtube video doesn't want to load.
I really hope there are some people with the same problem as I have and who know how to solve it.
 Thanks for any help
VVW

Comment: IE is a bitch! - but lets see some source code so we can help you out.

Comment: I've been driving my car for two years. And now it's broken. Kicking the tire does not work anymore. Anyone with the same problem? No offense, jsut give us an example of your code :) suggest to use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

ie6 and below don't understand border-color:transparent; ie8 (i think) and below don't understand :hover selectors that are not placed on an anchor element

Comment: isn't there a DOCTYPE to let IE support hover and border transparency?<br><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: off the top of my head, idk? there are plethora of solutions, although i'm pretty sure none of them are standards compliant, however they should get the job done.